# Permanently set kernel parameters [isolcpus] without grub?

Tags: kernel, parameter

Is there any way to set kernel parameters in an Ubuntu-based system without relying on grub? (not available in the target environment)

Specifically I want to set the isolcpus parameter to dedicate cores to an application.

This page titled: "[How to permanently set kernel parameters for Oracle on Linux](https://slashzeroconf.wordpress.com/2008/01/24/how-to-permanently-set-kernel-parameters-for-oracle-on-linux/)", describes a means of setting kernel parameters in a startup script.

Is there a way to set this parameter without a grub-style externally-supplied command line?  Can it be done without altering system binaries?

Answer (score 2):

`isolcpus` is a [kernel parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). It needs to be set on the kernel command line. From a look at the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c), there doesn't seem to be any way to set the same data structure ([`cpu_isolated_map`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=cpu_isolated_map) in `kernel/sched/core.c`) other than through this command line parameter.

All bootloaders allow setting kernel command line parameters, be they Grub, U-Boot or any other.

If you really can't add the command line parameter, you may be able to achieve a similar effect with CPU sets. The documentation of the `isolcpus` states that this can “cause problems and suboptimal load balancer performance”, though — it isn't suitable for all systems. See [the documentation of CPU sets](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cpusets.txt) and [whole one core dedicated to single process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583146/whole-one-core-dedicated-to-single-process)

Comment: [kernel-parameters.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt) now states that isolcpus is deprecated and _"it's strongly  advised to use cpusets instead to disable scheduler load balancing through the "cpuset.sched_load_balance" file. It offers a much more flexible interface where CPUs can move in and out of an isolated set anytime."_